# adding an element to a C# array from a text box

Tags: c#, arrays, textbox

I am struggling to add an element into an array from a text box using C# Windows Forms. hers what I have so far:

```
int[] id;

private void btnButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //INSERTION SORT
        int newItem = txtAddElement.text;

        //CODE HERE TO ADD ELEMENT TO ARRAY


        //CODE BELOW THEN SORTS ARRAY INTO CORRECT ORDER

        int element;
        int temp;

        for (int i = 1; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            element = i - 1;

            while (element >= 0 && id[element] > id[element + 1])
            {
                temp = id[element];
                id[element] = id[element + 1];
                id[element + 1] = temp;
            }
        }

        for (int i = 1; i < id.Length; i++)
        {
            lstPlayers.Items.Add(id[i]);
        }

        txtAddElement.Text = "";
    }
```

I know this insertion sort works because I have manually added some values in previously, however the basic part now seems to be tripping me up.

What I want is for the program to run with an empty array, as coded above, when I enter a value into `txtAddElement` I want  to use a button `btnAddToArray` to insert this value into the array. For example:

if i type 12 into `txtAddElement`, and then press `btnAddToArray`, i would like the array to now have 1 item of 12, If was was to then add another number via the `txtAddElement`, lets say 7, and press the  `btnAddToArray` button, I want the array to then have 2 values [12, 7] once I have mastered this then alls i need to do is add the insertion sort to this.

error:

CODE SNIPPET

```
   int[] id;

    private void btnLogOn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Array.Resize(ref id, id.Length + 1); //Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
        id[id.Length - 1] = Convert.ToInt16(txtLogOn.Text);

        //INSERTION SORT
        int element;
        int temp;
```

SOLVED:

```
  int[] id = new int[0];
```

Comment: why dont you use a List<int> instead?

Comment: Ok if button is clicked then this handler is invoked and sort works but it doesn't take any values from textbox directly. So where is the 'textbox part' of your code ?

Comment: the question I have been asked says use an array, otherwise I would have no issues with this

Comment: i am using the btnAddToArray to control the text box, once the button is pressed, I want this button to add the item into the array, and then it will empty the textbox

Comment: @dragonAMC show this code please as it is relevant

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't add to array. You should either use `List<T>` e.g.

```
  List<int> id;
  ...

  id.Add(123);
```

Or *re-size* the array (not recommended)

```
  int[] id;
  ... 
  Array.Resize(ref id, id.Length + 1);
  id[id.Length - 1] = 123;
```

Comment: (In general) Why wouldn't it be recommended to re-size the array ?

Comment: @Иво Недев: it could be *resource consuming* - array (unlike `List<T>`) is designed as constant size collection.

Comment: Because this logic is already implemented for you in Lists. And it's very likely that you'll make bugs while implementing what is already done.

Comment: each time I run the program the array will be null, so the array size isnt going to be that great, I have to show more that I can do it rather than whats the most efficient was. thankyou for your help, and I shall be using Lists normally from now on!!

Comment: ahh when adding in the resize it states "object reference not set to an instance of an object" see above

Comment: @dragonAMC: yes you *have to create* either array or List<int> before using them: `id = new int[someSize];`